# Different Handlers for URL patterns (same prefix) in vertx

Tags: vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I'm using vertx-4.x. I've sample url patterns like this:

```
api/v1/xyz_development/sse/reference/123456/  -> Handler1
api/v1/xyz_development/members/reference/789045/  -> Handler2
```

Please note **xyz_development**  is not fixed. It might change based on environment, so i don't want to hardcode it in URL patterns.

Requests with url pattern with **/sse** should be handled by **Handler1** and any other requests shoud be handled by **Handler2**.

I'm registering routes like this:

```
router.route("/sse/*).handler(new Handler1());
router.route("/api/v1/*).handler(new Handler2());
```

But when requests come with `/sse` , those are going to `Handler2` instead of `Handler1` as prefix is same (`/api/v1/...`)

I tried `subRouters` and `pathRegex()` API as well but couldn't make it work. Please suggest a way to acheive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple of trial and errors, finally found the solution. Defining routes like below worked:

```
router.route().pathRegex("/api/v1/.*/sse/.*").handler(new Handler1());
router.route().path("/api/v1/*").handler(new Handler2());
```

Now requests with **/sse** are being handled by **Handler1** and other requests are being handled by **Handler2**.

I welcome if there are other ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of your route declarations:

```
router.route("/api/v1/xyz_development/sse/*").handler(new Handler2());
router.route("/api/v1/xyz_development/*").handler(new Handler1());
```

And then requests for SSE will be handled by `Handler2`.

Comment: no.. the problem here is xyz_development is not fixed string.. it might change... only api/v1 is fixed.. I updated the same in problem description... anyways, i found the solution.. will update the thread..